# Forcing an optimization to satisfy constraints above all

Tags: matlab, optimization, gradient-descent, nonlinear-optimization

I'm currently using MATLAB's fmincon with interior-points to run this non-linear optimization problem I have. Depending on the initialization, my initial guess may already be quite close to the minimum objective value, at the same time grossly violating my constraints. This leads fmincon to pursue the minimization, even when it knows that constraints are being violated.

Is there a way to make fmincon temporarily ignore the gradient descent rule and perhaps commit to an ascent, till the constraints are satisfied and only then proceed with a more constrained minimization? I suppose I could tweak the initialization to get more favorable situations, but I would like to keep that as a last resort.

Comment: That is considered a poor initial point.

Comment: i think you are looking for "Method of Feasible Descent".  If you already have an acceptable feasible solution, then use "interior-point" algorithm option of fmincon.